# Что есть adapter с точки зрения mvc?

Tags: android, mvc, adapter

Раньше не особо заморачивался, а сейчас задумался: куда отнести адаптер с точки зрения `mvc`?
До сих пор использовал примерно такую структуру проекта:

+model\
|-----\data (модели данных)
|-----\database (хелпер и провайдер)
|-----\operation (сетевые операции и операции с БД)
+ui\ (activty, fragments ...)
+util\
|----\adapters (адаптеры)
|----........

Вопрос не в том, как это реализовать, вопрос в кошерности ─ как лучше организовать код.

Comment: Конетроллер?

Comment: @Suvitruf: мне понравилась ваша опечатка.

Comment: В вашей структуре не хватает части, отвечающей за "С" (Контроллер). Как раз к нему и надо относить адаптеры...    
@Suvitruf, сижу уже минуту и ржу...

Comment: @metalurgus да, забавно вышло )

Comment: @Suvitruf, только не исправляйте!!

Comment: @metalurgus у меня просто обычно логика контролера выполняется в  activity и иногда в сервисе, activity лично мне как то удобнее в ui держать. Не могу определится модель или контролер, хотя банда четырех его в отдельный паттерон выносит, и им я склонен верить )) Есть предложение показать у кого какая структура ─ лично меня немного огорчает что 90% информации в буржуйском нете ))